# What is the correct subnet mask to use on a Class B network with a 10-bit subnet identifier?

Tags: networking, subnet

I thought it was D but I got it wrong does anyone know what the correct answer is and why?

A. 255.192.255.255

B. 255.255.255.192

C. 255.255.192.0

D. 255.192.0.0

Comment: Class B networks no longer exist. They have been replaced by CIRD decades ago. The only place you will find them in is outdated documentation.

Comment: @Hennes means CIDR (not CIRD).  When I teach networking, I tell people that the IPv4 classes are only relevant for tests and communication with people who use the terminology.  We don't use classes for their earlier intended purpose, which had to do with address allocation. But, if someone asks for a class B network in a range described by RFC 1918, I'd be quite wrong to give them the 192.168 address.  Some people do still refer to something like a "Class C network" (or "class C address" or "class C subnet"), so familiarity with the terminology may still be a bit useful.  Plus, it's oft tested

Comment: /me peers at the CCNA routing and switching guide next to him... It indeed uses decades old terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IP address has 32 bits.  If 10 bits are used to identify the subnet, that leaves 22 bits for the host.  The subnet identifier would be
 11111111110000000000000000000000
which, with dots added for "binary dotted" notation, would look like:
11111111.11000000.00000000.00000000
which would be 255.192.0.0

Question #1: Does anyone know what the correct answer is?
Yes.  It is D.

Question #2: Why?
As described above.

Implied question #3: What did I do wrong?
Nothing.  Somebody did something wrong, and it wasn't you.  It was whoever determined the correct answer for the test.

Unless... perhaps they were going for another terminology, which could make some sense.
One could say that 255.0.0.0 is implied for class A, and is the "network mask".  Likewise, 255.255.0.0 would be the "network mask" for class B.  Then, if you wanted to have additional bits to identify subnets within a class B network, a person could use up 10 additional bits for subnets within that network.  If you look at it that way, the 255.255. at the start is implied, so then you would add 255.192 after that, resulting in answer B.  If that's what they meant, well, I say it's a crummy trick question, but I do suppose that is another way to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You tried interpreting "10-bit subnet identifier" as 10 bits total, however, according to [RFC 950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc950#page-6), the subnet part is *next to* the classful network part, giving you Class B + 10-bit subnet = 26 bits total (that is, a /26 network). This would use a netmask of `255.255.255.192`.

```
  For example, the Internet address might be interpreted as:

     <network-number><subnet-number><host-number>

  ....

  For example, on a Class B network with a 6-bit wide subnet field,
  an address would be broken down like this:

                       1                   2                   3
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
  |1 0|        NETWORK            |  SUBNET   |    Host Number    |
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

**Side note**

Interestingly, the document did also allow non-contiguous masks, which means even answer A was technically possible, even if wrong for *this* question. (This also shows just how old your ques­tion­naire is...) Fortunately, such heresy was later forbidden.